# Simplest way to track ip address of visitors of jekyll website

Tags: jekyll, ip-address, jekyll-theme

I am using this code for the website:https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio. Since Google Analytics does not allow IP addresses of visitors to be tracked, can someone please let me know of any good alternate solution to track IP address and location. Also, please tell how to integrate it into the above linked code.

Answer (score 0):

What about https://matomo.org, it is an alternative to google analytics, it can be hosted on your own server. Then you can track IP addresses. But be aware inside the EU there is the DSGVO and GDPR, so take care of your users privacy!

The tracking code can be played as JS in your default layout.